# RegisterEventSourceA leak and handle limits?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, handle

We have a piece of code running that we know has a handle leak. It looks a little bit like:

```
WORD wType = EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE;
DWORD eventID = 20001;

HANDLE hlog = RegisterEventSourceA(NULL, "TestLog");
if (NULL != hlog)
{
  LPCSTR s[1];
  s[0] = "test writing to event log";
  ReportEventA(hlog, wType, 0, eventID, NULL, 1, 0, s, NULL);
  // DeregisterEventSource(hlog);
}
else
{
  // could not RegisterEventSourceA             
  DWORD err = GetLastError();       
  printf("%d", err);
}
```

The bug in the code is DeregisterEventSource() is not being called. It is leaking handles returned by RegisterEventSourceA().

We did some testing and it appears that RegisterEventSourceA() will return NULL after 65535 calls. When hlog is NULL, GetLastErorr() returns 8 (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY).

I tested this on Windows 10 x64.

Is 65535 the limit of handles for RegisterEventSourceA?

Why is this limit this different than other handle limits?

When I look in task manager or sysinternals procexplorer, I don't see a large number of handles associated with the process. I only see about 200. Why aren't these handles reported?

When I run sysinternals TestLimit64, it shows:

```
C:\>Testlimit64.exe -h

Testlimit v5.24 - test Windows limits Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Mark
Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Process ID: 77968

Creating handles... Created 16711496 handles. Lasterror: 1450
```

Comment: because exist different types of handles. exist so called kernel handles - by fact index in process handle table. only this handles can be enumerated for process with external tool. but some api can return not kernel handle but some another handle type. this can be pointer (may be even mangled) to some data structure, may be index in the some private table. etc. kernel handles closed via `NtClose` (`CloseHandle`). if api use another function for close handle - this already say that faster of all this not kenel handle (exception `closesocket` here )

Comment: According to [Kernel Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/kernel-objects): "*Kernel object handles are process specific. That is, a process must either create the object or open an existing object to obtain a kernel object handle. The per-process limit on kernel handles is 2^24. However, handles are stored in the paged pool, so the actual number of handles you can create is based on available memory. The number of handles that you can create on 32-bit Windows is significantly lower than 2^24.*" And `RegisterEventSource` is listed as creating a Kernel Object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - wrong listed. really it not return kernel handle

Comment: I tested your code piece on Windows 10 x64. I didn't reach the "limit" after created about 176,000 handles successfully. The limit here seems that *Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.*. However, there is a limit for `USER` handles to menus, it is 10000. You can reach it using this command: `Testlimit64.exe -u`. The error message is "The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects." [Why is the limit of window handles per process 10,000?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070718-00/?p=25963)